# FedEx Web Services - Printing Return Slip After Shipment In PHP

Tags: php, soap, fedex

I'm having a hard time understanding what kind of SOAP request is required.  I'm currently printing shipments in the test environment very easily and deleting them as required.  I have a case where

- My company ships a parcel through the `processShipment` service
- The customer decides they don't want it
- The customer contacts customer support
- Customer support generates a label to send to the customer with the option that either the company pays (if product was defective, for example) for the shipment or the customer pays for the parcel (if the customer decided they don't like the product), who will take it to a FedEx drop site or service center to send back the parcel

Point #4 is important in that I want to either have the customer pay for it or the company to pay for it, which is why I want the customer to go to a Fedex Drop site or service center.

I do not want to generate a tag service - I don't want someone from FedEx to go to the customer's house and pick up the package and generate a slip on site (at least not right now).  I also don't want to generate a return slip when the shipment is created, and I don't want to include it in the box for a return.

A few more considerations:

- How does customs payments factor into this?
- I'd like to be able to generate the slip and send it through our web application, and not from FedEx

I've read both the 2013 and 2014 Developer Guides for FedEx web services but I haven't been able to find the correct call to make.